# Macro to Save As spreadsheet in same folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Save As an excel spreadsheet into the same folder that the original Excel file is in.

Currently, the file is saved on my Desktop.

However, when I run this code, it saves it to my Documents folder.

I do not want to hard code it to save to my Desktop everytime, but wherever the original Excel happens to be.

My attempt below. Thank you for your help!

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="Name"
```

Comment: The folder containing the Excel workbook is `ThisWorkbook.Path`.  Try filename := `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Name"`.  Warning: this will probably not work if you use OneDrive.  I can provide a routine that handles the faulty URL returned by `ThisWorkbook.Path` if the Excel workbook is within OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

here for ur ref.

```
Sub testSave()
'using Application.PathSeparator to identfy the "/" or "\"
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
fName = "yourfilename"

' 51 means *.xlsx, for detais, check https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & fName, FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```